# Change Default Language in WMAppManifest.xml

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, phonegap-build

I have a XAP file but it has no language specified and the App is in Dutch.
The XAP is built by PhoneGap Build.

I downloaded the xap file, unzipped it and changed the WMAppManifest.xml file.

I've added, to the specifications:

```
<DefaultLanguage xmlns="" code="nl-NL" />
```

Just like it says:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769509(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_DEFAULTLANGUAGEandLANGUAGESelements

But after uploading the xap file it get turned down because DefaultLanguage isn't allowed there.

EDITED; Added the complete file:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsphone/2009/deployment"    AppPlatformVersion="7.1">
    <DefaultLanguage xmlns="" code="nl-NL" />

    <App ProductID="{01bc12cd-49ae-bffa-004d-858ebc07ee7c}" RuntimeType="Silverlight"  Title="Gaandeweg" Version="1.0.2.0" Publisher="Bart Lamot" xmlns="" Genre="apps.normal"  Author="Bart Lamot" Description="Dit...">

<IconPath IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">ApplicationIcon.png</IconPath>
<Capabilities>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_CONTACTS"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_ISV_CAMERA"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_LOCATION"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MICROPHONE"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_HW_FRONTCAMERA"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT"/>
</Capabilities>

<Tasks>
  <DefaultTask NavigationPage="MainPage.xaml" Name="_default"/>
</Tasks>
<Tokens>
  <PrimaryToken TaskName="_default" TokenID="Cordova_1._5._0_Starter1Token">
    <TemplateType5>
      <BackgroundImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Background.png</BackgroundImageURI>
      <Count>0</Count>
      <Title>Cordova_1._5._0_Starter1</Title>
    </TemplateType5>
  </PrimaryToken>
 </Tokens>
 </App>
 </Deployment>


<!-- WPSDK Version 7.1.7720.0 -->
```

Comment: Where did you get this XAP?

Comment: Phongap build http://build.phonegap.com

Comment: Please post the full manifest file in your question, with `DefaultLanguage` added.

Comment: Added the xml to the original post

Comment: Exactly how did you implement that XML for the PhoneGap Build service? Somewhere inside config.xml?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are working on a Windows Phone 7.1 application, `DefaultLanguage` element is not supported in WMAppManifest.xml. Instead, you need to use `[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute("en-US")]` in **AssemblyInfo.cs**.

Look at the XML namespace - for 7.1 you have `http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsphone/2009/deployment`. For **DefaultLanguage** to work, you need `http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsphone/2012/deployment` (Windows Phone 8 apps).

Comment: Am I right that this file is used at compile time and not part of a XAP package?

Comment: AssemblyInfo - yes. It ends up as a part of the package, but not as a cs file.

Comment: Is there a way to edit this in the package? It is being build in the cloud, so I can't change AssemblyInfo.

Comment: Their bug for the locale issue is still open. The only solution available at this time is documented here: http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/_winphone_does_not_support_locales?page=1#reply_11256215

Comment: Thnx Den for all the info. You have been a great help.

Comment: Exactly how are you supposed to merge the XML parameters shown at Windows Dev Center into the config.xml used by PhoneGap build? The chances of having compatible syntax is 0.0002%, this will fail.